# set border for nested divs in twitter bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

i have a layout like this:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="span9">
    span 9
       <div class="row">
           <div class="span5">
           span5 
           </div>
           <div class="span4">
           span4
           </div>
       </div>
    </div>
    <div class="span3">
    span 3
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<style>
.span9
{
border:1px solid black;
-webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
-moz-box-sizing: border-box;
box-sizing: border-box;
}
</style>
```

how can i set a border for span9?

**box-size** fix span3 position but span4 and span5 position break.

Answer (score 1):

The `border` property will add to the width of the element you apply it to. Generally, I find that it's problematic to add this to any of the grid elements (ie. .container, .row or .span(x)). Instead, I add an additional container inside to apply the style(s) to. For example:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="span9">
            <div class="addBorder">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="span5">
                        span5 
                    </div>
                    <div class="span4">
                        span4
                    </div>
                </div>              
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="span3">
            span 3
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

.addBorder {
    border: 1px solid black;
}
```

Alternatively, if you must add it to the span, you just need to add -fluid to the row selector.

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row-fluid">
        <div class="span9">
            span 9
            <div class="row">
                <div class="span5">
                    span5 
                </div>
                <div class="span4">
                    span4
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="span3">
            span 3
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

.span9 {
    border: 1px solid black;
}
```